# Magento Command Line steps for updating code files on server in Production

Tags: production-mode, maintenance

What are the steps to add a module on Production Store Site for Magento.  Do I switch to maintenance mode from Production then run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and other commands then turn off maintenance mode then switch back to production? Just wanted to make sure the proper way to update a production site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps :-

```
1- set maintenance mode
php bin/magento maintenance:enable

2- Upload module or use composer to install module using cli

3- Enable module
php bin/magento module:enable MyCompany_MyModule

4- upgrade database
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

5-compile your code
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

6-static content deploy 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

7-reindex (optional)
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

8-clear cache
php bin/magento cache:flush

9-Disable maintenance mode
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: Hi, I had one more question about this. Should I `rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*` before upgrading or updating a new module? Does removing those files help?

Comment: Also, today when I tried putting up a new module to production I got an error. `The directory "/var/www/vhosts/upperlimitsinc.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/var/www/vhosts/upperlimitsinc.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento): Directory not empty`. 

Should I `rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/generation/* var/di/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/*` Before Enabling Module?

Comment: The error you have mentioned, that is because of improper permission to the folder. Also deleting the folders you've mentioned will solve this error. But please take care while using this rm rf command as it used to delete. Just delete the folders that are regenerated, and execute the commands, it should work.

Comment: Hi, @Harmendra I have another question. If I am just changing a .phtml file on Production site. Do I need to put site in macitence mode to make this change? Or can I just change the file then run `php bin/magento cache:flush` from backend with out having to put Production 
 site into maintenance mode?

Comment: No need to put site on maintenance mode, just delete cache using command - php bin/magento c:c & phtml changes will be visible.

Comment: Hi @Hamendra. One more question. Thanks for all the help. If I run re-index from SSH on Production, can I run re-index from SSH with out putting site in maintenance mode? Or when running re-index from SSH I should put site in maintenance mode?

Comment: Yes, you can run re-index from SSH on producttion without putting site in maintenance mode. That's fine if you have less then 10 or 20k products. If there are more then putting site on maintenance mode would be a great idea.

Comment: Hi @Hamendra, One more question. Sorry for all the questions. Do you have to put store in maintenance mode if I am just making a small change to a phtml file? Or can I just quickly make the change in the file and run cache flush?

Comment: Hi, there is no need to put store in maintenance mode, if you are making changes in phtml file, just cache clear will work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. And My last question, So sorry. If you have a Live site in Production Mode.  Should you ever put the live site back in Developer mode if you ever need to debug anything? Or always keep the Live site in Production mode? This site has customers coming to it.

Or just use our testing site for debugging and keep Live site in Production mode always?

Comment: keep live site in Production mode always, use testing site for debugging
fix issue if any in testing site & then move that fix into live site.

Comment: Hi, sorry one more question. If I make changes to a helper file on Live site. Such as `app\cod\Aheadgroups\Authorizenetcim\Helper\GatewayXml.php`. What Magento commands should I run after making changes to this helper php file?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it depends what changes you have made to helper file,
if you have added some class in constructor then you need to run
php bin/magento setup:di:compile or if you just made some changes in existing function php bin/magento c:c is enough.

Comment: You can contact me on my email/skype.
if you have any questions on magento customizations or in web development.
Also if you'd like we can collaborate & work on magento based projects :)

Comment: Hi, Hamendra! Thank you, that would be great. My Skype name is live:jonathanhelvey and my email is jonathanhelvey27@gmail.com. Feel free to email or Skype me anytime! Thanks for all the help and it would be great to collaborate in the future! Look forward to it.